# Is this set of $2\times 2$ matrices a group?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $n$ be a fixed positive integer. I have then been asked to determine whether the set $G$ of all real $2\times 2$ matrices $A$ such that $\displaystyle \det(A)=\frac{m}{n^{t}} \in \mathbb{Q}$ where $m$ is a strictly positive integer (i.e., $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, where $m>0$, $m \neq 0$); and $t$ is a nonnegative integer (i.e., $t \in \mathbb{Z}$, where $t \geq 0$) forms a group under multiplication.

I'm thinking that $G$ is **NOT** a group, because it does not necessarily contain the inverses of every $A \in G$:

Recall the result that if $B$ is any invertible matrix, then $\displaystyle \det(B^{-1})=\frac{1}{det(B)}$. So, suppose that $A \in G$. Then, $\displaystyle \det(A^{-1})= \frac{1}{\displaystyle \left(\frac{m}{n^{t}}\right)} = \frac{n^{t}}{m}$ $\implies$ $A^{-1} \notin G$, since $n$ is fixed, and the denominator of determinants of matrices in $G$ must contain a nonnegative integer power of $n$, and $\det(A^{-1})$ does not.

I thought maybe then, we could say that it has $n^{0}$ in the denominator, but even then, we're not guaranteed that $\displaystyle \frac{n^{t}}{m}$ is an integer, and the numerator of the determinant of a matrix in $G$ must contain a strictly positive integer.

Does this show that $G$ is not a group?

Comment: Yes, if you are not garantueed the existence of inverses then it isnt a group but rather a semigroup

Comment: @ZelosMalum, so let's say instead that we were checking whether $H$, the set of all $2\times 2$ matrices $A$ such that $\det(A)=n^{t}$ was a group. Now, that would not be closed under inverses either, right? B/c $\displaystyle \det(A^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\det(A)} = \frac{1}{n^{t}} = \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{t}$ is not a nonnegative integer power of $n$?

Comment: Correct, it isn't a non-negative power anymore then. If you extend to include all integers it is a group however.

Comment: @ZelosMalum, or if $n=1$.

Comment: well yes that trivial case